# In movies OR in the movies?

Tags: articles

**In the movies** means:

> **the movies**
>
> a : **a showing of a movie in a theater** We are going to the movies
> tonight. [=we are going to see a movie tonight]
>
> **also : a movie theater** What's (playing/showing) at the movies?
>
> b : **the business of making movies : the film industry** He wants to
> work in the movies.

But if I want to say this, do I need "the" or not?

**1 I've seen this trick in the movies.**

**2 I've seen this trick in movies.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either will do.

"I've seen this trick in movies": there is more than one movie I've seen in which I saw this trick;

"I've seen this trick in the movies": I've seen the trick at least once while watching the movies (originally "the moving pictures").

Aside from all the cultural baggage attached especially to the second sentence, the big semantic difference between the two is that the first implies I've seen this trick in a movie at least twice, and in the second, even having seen it once would make the sentence true.